# Single sign-on with dynamics 2011 + ADFS 2.0- doesn't work for modal window

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, single-sign-on, adfs2.0

**Background:**

I have an installation of dynamics crm 2011 (IFD), and I have an ASP.net website in which I want to retrieve the logged-in user's details.

I followed the walkthrough to create a website which is configured as a relying party, and it seems to be working ok; I log on to crm, then browse to my website, and the user's credentials are available there as necessary.

**The issue:**

In some cases I want to open one of my web pages as a modal dialog from within the CRM website (meaning- a user logs on to the CRM website, presses a button, and a modal dialog displaying one of my pages appears).

In that case, my web page doesn't display anything at all- the address bar indicates that it's loading the sts server's signon page, but nothing actually happens and the window is frozen.

looking at the ADFS trace I can see 2 warning log entries, as follows:

```
Ignoring Invalid entry 'signoutCleanup;https%3a%2f%2fMyCrm.dev.com%3a4444%2f&walkthrough&https%3a%2f%2fMyCrm.dev.com%3a4444%2fdefault.aspx&https%3a%2f%2fMyCrm.dev.com%3a4444%2fdefault.aspx' in signout cookie.


Ignoring Invalid entry 'signoutCleanup;https%3a%2f%2fMyCrm.dev.com%3a444%2f&CRM+IFD+Relying+Party&https%3a%2f%2fauth.dev.com%3a444%2f&https%3a%2f%2fauth.dev.com%3a444%2f' in signout cookie.
```

Now the strange thing is that if I browse via a non-modal window to one of my webpages, and then open that same modal dialog again- it works fine.

Looking at the ADFS logs for browsing the non-modal dialog I can see one warning- the latter from before:

```
Ignoring Invalid entry 'signoutCleanup;https%3a%2f%2fMyCrm.dev.com%3a444%2f&CRM+IFD+Relying+Party&https%3a%2f%2fauth.dev.com%3a444%2f&https%3a%2f%2fauth.dev.com%3a444%2f' in signout cookie.
```

after that, any browsing (be it modal or non modal) to my web page works fine, without warnings on ADFS.

Can anyone shed any light on this behaviour?